# WP Visual composer jquery conflict woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with jquery, i see this in the developer console (F12)
I use wordpress with visual composer version 5.1.1
Woocommerce version 3.0.8
The url is https://new.demuynck-printing.be

When i disable visual composer then the error is gone.
Anybody have an idea how to fix this error?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have changed the file ,

Check the original file here : `https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.min.js#L1`

If you want changes inside add-to-cart.min.js then dequeue the file first and include it in the theme/child-theme

Comment: Thanks! +1 . Many thanks the error is now gone and everything works